# Редиректы с Nginx

Tags: django, nginx, веб-сервер, redirect

Доброго времени.
Есть сервер который обеспечивает работу сайта и нескольких микросервисов. На основном сайте используется Django + gunicorn + Nginx. 
Есть страницы:
https://example.com/page - она даёт ответ 200 и всё гут. 
https://example.com/page/ - отдаёт 404.
Вопрос как со страниц со слешем сделать редирект на страницы без слеша посредством nginx? 
Заранее всем спасибо!

Comment: Надо просто правильно прописать паттерны в urls.py

Comment: отлично, спасибо. а что насчёт nginx конфига?

Answer (score 0):

Возвратит постоянное перенаправление с кодом 301 для любого uri заканчивающегося слэшем:

```
server {
    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы работаете в Linux на основе CentOS или Red Hat, файлы конфигурации как правило расположены в директории /etc/nginx/conf.d/. В Linux на основе Ubuntu или Debian — в директории /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/.

Сама настройка должна выглядеть примерно так:

```
server {
    #...
    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
    #...
}
```